# yii2 ajax validation error in widget, yii\web\Response

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I'm getting error from yii\web\Response when I use ajax validation.

> Object of class yii\web\Response could not be converted to string

widget:

```
    public function run()
{
    $model = new Participants();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $list = implode( ", ",$model->sections);
        $model->sections = $list;
        $model->save();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash(Alert::TYPE_SUCCESS, [
            [
                'title' => 'Congratulations!',
                'text' => 'You are registered on the forum. Check out your email to get news about forum.',
                'confirmButtonText' => 'Done!',
            ]
        ]);
        return Yii::$app->controller->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);
    }

    return $this->render('header', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

view of widget:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();?>
...
<?= $form->field($model, 'email', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true])->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Email']); ?>
```

how I can solve this error? P.S. yii version - 2.0.17-dev

Comment: this does not work anymore with the latest version 2.0.15.1, event the default ActiveForm validation does not work – Muhammad Omer Aslam. Source (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404481/yii2-bootstrap-modal-form-validation-ajax-any-insight-on-strange-behavior#comment-93312223)

Comment: i cant guess if you tried to tag me in reference to the link you have added in the comment or for looking into the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\yii\base\Widget::run()` must return a string (all widgets basically)

All you should do within method `run()` is output or render content and you're attempting to return a Response object by way of `return ActiveForm::validate($model);` and `return Yii::$app->controller->redirect(..)`

i suggest you move all the code that supposed to handle form submission to it's own action

```
SiteController extends controller {


    public function actionRegisterParticipant {
        $model = new Participants();
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $list = implode(", ", $model->sections);
            $model->sections = $list;
            $model->save();
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash(Alert::TYPE_SUCCESS, [
                [
                    'title'             => 'Congratulations!',
                    'text'              => 'You are registered on the forum. Check out your email to get news about forum.',
                    'confirmButtonText' => 'Done!',
                ]
            ]);
            return Yii::$app->controller->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);
        }
    // ...
}
```

and the form in the widget view should always point to this action:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => 'site/register-participant']);?>
...
<?= $form->field($model, 'email', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true])->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Email']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Widget should return string as a result, but `return Yii::$app->controller->redirect()` returns `Response` object with configured redirection. If you want to redirect inside of widget you should use something like that:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    Yii::$app->controller->asJson(ActiveForm::validate($model));
    Yii::$app->end();
}

// ...

Yii::$app->session->setFlash(/* ... */);
Yii::$app->controller->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);
Yii::$app->end();
```

But this smells like a bad design - widget should not be responsible for controlling application flow. It is better to handle user input in regular action/controller.

Comment: I already tried this way, but doesnt work. but thx for suggestion.